# SQSClient token expires; need auto refresh

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I have the following:

```
    AWSCredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain();
    final AWSCredentials credentials;
    try {
        credentials = credentialsProvider.getCredentials();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.error("AWS profile exception: {}", e);
        throw new AmazonClientException(e.getMessage());
    }

    AmazonSQSClientBuilder sqsClientBuilder = AmazonSQSClientBuilder.standard();
    sqsClientBuilder.setCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(credentials));
    sqsClientBuilder.setRegion(config.getAwsRegion());

    AmazonSQS sqsClient = sqsClientBuilder.build();
```

However, after a while, I get `com.amazonaws.services.sqs.model.AmazonSQSException: The security token included in the request is expired (Service: AmazonSQS; Status Code: 403; Error Code: ExpiredToken`

How can I setup my client so it automatically refreshes the client?

Comment: What is your client? An EC2 instance?

Comment: @Henry Yes it is

Comment: And how are you providing credentials? It should be through an IAM Role - is it?

Comment: Side-comment: There is some [sample SQS Java code in the SQS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-sqs-message-queues.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't set the credentials manually (.getCredentials()), aws sdk (1.10.x) will automatically refresh tokens if provider is passed as constructor arg.

`sqs=new AmazonSQSClient( new DefaultAWSCredentialsProviderChain());`

As in your case, You may skip setting credentials as `AmazonSQSClientBuilder` by default gets credentials from `DefaultAWSCredentialProviderChain()` as per [doc](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/client/builder/AwsClientBuilder.html#setCredentials-com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentialsProvider-)